# How to display base64 image in django admin?

Tags: django, base64, django-admin

I have legacy software that stores the institutions logo through django's BinaryField, I need to show this image on the django admin record editing page

this my admin:

```
class InstituicaoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['ds_instituicao', 'sigla']
    search_fields = ['ds_instituicao']
    formfield_overrides = {
        BinaryField: {'widget': BinaryFileInput()},
    }
    readonly_fields = ["imagem_logo",]

    def imagem_logo(self, obj):
        base64Encoded = base64.b64encode(obj.logo)
        return mark_safe('<img src="data:;base64,base64Encoded">')
```

This not work

I want some like this: [Image_FIeld](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/imagefield.html)

Comment: You might find answers to this Question useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `format_html` instead of `mark_safe`:

```
    def imagem_logo(self, obj):
        base64Encoded = base64.b64encode(obj.logo)
        return format_html('<img src="data:;base64,{}">', base64Encoded)
```

See the docs at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html